# Changing the value of one table through a form connected to another table

Tags: join, ms-access-2010

I have a Access database that has a inventory page. I have created a sales form with a drop down box with the inventory items inside of it. This form also has subtotal, tax and total on it. I have a sold button.

Drop down:

```
ID, Product Name, Quantity, Price
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. Remove 1 item from the inventory table.
2. Add a record to the sales table with the product ID.

I have figured out how to create a record, but I don't know how to pull items from another table to the table I am working with through the form.

Inventory Table:

```
ID, sale/parts, Type, Model, quantity, base value, sale value
```

Sale table:

```
ID, inventory.id, subtotal, tax, total
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you require this to happen on just one form? The simplest way (in Access) is to have one form per table. In this case, a main form with 2 subforms (one for inventory, one for sales). This way you get to keep all the Access simplicity and still update multiple tables.

The other route is to write custom multi-table SQL and use one form, but that route requires more complex knowledge and take away the Access layer of simplicity.

The former solution can still graphically appear to be one form (at runtime).

Comment: The main reason I am trying to do this is because I work for a mom and pop shop. They have been using paper documents to keep track of everything. This was good back when they had no more than 50 people in a single week. They now have 50 people in a single day. The paper is becoming cumbersome for them. They asked me to help bring them into the digital age. I'm trying to make something easy for them to use. So a single form for sale that subtracts from the inventory makes the sale easier. I'm almost finished, all i need to do is get around this problem.

Comment: Again, for your purposes (the backend design) you can do this easily with a form/subform design pattern. From the front end (runtime, the form) it will look like one form.

Comment: What did you end up doing?